# Gatling 2 - Logback Debug Not Outputting JSON Body - Content Type Application/Json

Tags: logback, gatling

I am using Gatling 2, below is my `logback.xml` configuration.

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %logger{15} - %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
        <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
    </encoder>
</appender>

 <!--Uncomment for logging ALL HTTP request and responses-->
    <logger name="io.gatling.http.ahc" level="TRACE" />
<!-- Uncomment for logging ONLY FAILED HTTP request and responses -->
<!--    <logger name="io.gatling.http.ahc" level="DEBUG" /> -->

<root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>
```

When viewing the log in the console I see

```
Content-Length: [1381]
Keep-Alive: [timeout=5, max=98]
Connection: [Keep-Alive]
Content-Type: [application/json]
```

However, I do not see any of the JSON body in the debugging info. I hacked my code and changed `Content-Type` from `application/json` to `text/html` and receive the following:

```
Connection: [Keep-Alive]
Content-Type: [text/html]
Content-Encoding: [gzip]
Content-Length: [1381]

body=
{"items":[data_here]}}
```

Is there any way I can configure gatling or logback to display this JSON body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having something not working as you, as a beginner, expect it, doesn't necessarily mean its weird. There can be good reasons for such behavior.

Here, it's so that chunks are not held in memory, assembled and decoded when not required.
[Reading](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.3/http/http_protocol.html#response-chunks-discarding) [the documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.3/http/http_request.html#response-chunks-discarding) usually helps.

Then, you can also enable DEBUG logging on the "io.gatling.http" logger.
Just for the record, I filled an [issue](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/2509) to improve this.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had come across that in the manual before, but assumed it was counteracted when I did the `Uncomment for logging ALL HTTP request and responses` thing. And don't worry, I wasn't dissing your tool or anything! I'd be interested in contributing to fill the issue you raised, what IDE setup, etc are you using to develop gatling?

Comment: Thanks for that. Chat to you more on GitHub!

Comment: The lecture is uncalled for. Your docs should mention the behavior in the section on logging rather than burying it deep under all the minutiae of HTTP protocol settings.

Answer (score -1):

Okay. Gatling is weird.

It automatically logs the body for `text/html` and does not for `application/json` unless it deems there is a reason to log it!

To output the json body I added `.check(bodyString.exists)` to my http request and it displayed correctly in the log file.

Edit:

[Properly fixed in this commit](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/commit/a825c8d727f155e8583b41ec39bfa5ce49fa0ea8)

Added extra lines to my `logback.xml`

```
<!-- Uncomment for logging ALL HTTP request and responses -->
        <logger name="io.gatling.http.ahc" level="TRACE" />
        <logger name="io.gatling.http.response" level="TRACE" />
<!-- Uncomment for logging ONLY FAILED HTTP request and responses -->
<!--    <logger name="io.gatling.http.ahc" level="DEBUG" /> -->
<!--    <logger name="io.gatling.http.response" level="DEBUG" /> -->
```